# What is the difference between => and ->?

Tags: postgresql, psql

The command prompt sometimes switches between `=>` and `->` when using the interactive terminal `psql`.  It's not clear to me what this indicates.

For example,

```
$ psql postgres
psql (9.5.10)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> /h
postgres->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see the `->`, it is letting the user know that the current line is a continuation of an incomplete statement.  The previous command was not properly ended.  In other words, it is waiting for you to end the statement with a `;`.  See this example of a query broken up into three different lines.  It doesn't run my query until I end the statement with a semi-colon.

```
test=> select * from
test-> pg_catalog.pg_tables
test-> where tablename='test';
 schemaname | tablename | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes 
------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------,
(0 rows)
```

Comment: In your specific example, I think you meant to write "\h" not "/h".  "\h" is also a legal completed statement.